# How to delete empty lists in a 2Dlist

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

I have a 2D list, but havent filled in every list in the 2D list. So the 2D list contains some lists, but those lists are not all filled in. If they arent filled in, I want to delete those. How do I do this? This is what I got so far:

```
List<List<string>> list = new List<List<string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < list.count;i++) 
{ 
  if (list[i][0] == "") //Or has it to be == NULL?
  { 
     list[i].Remove();  //.Remove tells me it takes 0 arguments
  } 
}
```

Comment: Which type of List is list?

Comment: of strings, List<List<string>>

Comment: I assume you tried different ways and checked if it actually removed empty lists. Can you come up with some arguments why the methods you used didn't succeed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, the line

```
if (list[i][0] == "") //Or has it to be == NULL?
```

assumes that the sublist at index `i` has at least one element.

```
list[i].Remove();  //.Remove tells me it takes 0 arguments
```

To remove an item at a specific index, you would have to use [`RemoveAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
list.RemoveAt[i]
```

When you want to use [`Remove`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx), you have to pass the object you want to remove:

```
list.Remove(list[i])
```

But note that you should not change `list` while using it in a `for` loop, since `list.Count` is evaluated at the start of the loop, and when you remove an item, you'll hit an out-of-bounds error.

---

It's not entirely clear to me when you actually want to remove a sublist, but to remove all sublists from `list` that are

- `null` (`l == null`)
- empty (`!l.Any()`)
- or just contain empty strings (`l.All(string.IsNullOrEmpty)`)

simply use the [`RemoveAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wdka673a(v=vs.110).aspx) method like this:

```
list.RemoveAll(l => l == null || !l.Any() || l.All(string.IsNullOrEmpty));
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
list[i].Remove();  //.Remove tells me it takes 0 arguments
```

Use

```
list.RemoveAt(I);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.count;i++) 
{ 
  list[i].RemoveAll(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace); 
}
```

Comment: I think this question is to basic to really explain this code. It's quite self explaining.